# Push or remove object from array if object is in array in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for more elegant and efficient way to toggle object in array.

So my arr is:

```
let arr = [
   {id: 2},
   {id: 3},
   ...
]
```

Now I'm doing it like this:

```
if (arr.find(function(element) { return element.id === upload.id } )) {
    arr = arr.filter(function(element) {
        return element.id !== upload.id;
    });
}
else {
    arr.push(upload)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const index = arr.findIndex(function(element) { return element.id === upload.id });
if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
}) else {
    arr.push(upload);
}
```

Comment: Ok, my idea is find index of seeking element and if exists remove item from array using splice.

Comment: Edit the question and add some meaningful comments on them, guide user to understand the solution you provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you toggle the object often, you could use a hash table for the indices of the array.

```
var hash = Object.create(null);

function update(array, item) {
    if (hash[item.id] !== undefined) {
        array.slice(hash[item.id], 1);
        hash[item.id] = undefined;
    } else {
        hash[item.id] = array.push(item) - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const toggle = (arr, obj) => arr.includes(obj) ? arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj), 1) : arr.push(obj);
```

Comment: Your option won't work, becuase it doesn't check id.